# Can't Access Checkbox in Datagrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

It's my xaml:

```
<Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pilih" Width="50" IsReadOnly="False">
                    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Height="23" Name="ckPilih" Checked="ckPilih_Checked">
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

when i want to use it(ckPilih) in .cs it can't access

Answer (score 1):

You won't have direct access to this checkbox in code behind because the scope of `ckPilih` is only inside the `DataTemplate`

On the side note, I am not sure about your use case but it is not usually recommended to access the `checkbox` or any other control inside `DataTemplate` in this manner. You should always try to bind the `DataGrid` with your `datasource`. DataGrid will then automatically reflect the changes in `DataSource`

Answer (score 0):

It is DataTemplate element. you can access it only in your DataTemplate definition. Instead of this, you should use `DataGrid.Rows[i].Cell[j].Children` property to access collection of controls in a cell.

Comment: there is not dataGrid.Rows in WPF, am i missing something?

Comment: may be. but i'm sure you know the way to access (i,j) cell :)

Comment: i have searched but i didn't get it, Anybody can help me?

Comment: may be Items is the answer for your question? use msdn to read more about it!